# Unity 5 moving planets in a circular or elliptical path (orbits)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have:

```
void Update () {
    transform.RotateAround(transform.parent.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), orbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Which gives me a very basic circular orbit.

What do I need to do to get varied elliptical orbits (planets are generated randomly per star and so I would also like to give them random orbit paths)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use RotateAround. you will have to make your own function

try to use:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/133373/moving-object-in-a-ellipse-motion.html

```
x, y: center of the ellipse
a, b: semimajor and semiminor axes
```

the code:

```
 var a : int;
 var b : int;
 var x: int;

 var y : int;
 var alpha : int;
 var X : int;
 var Y : int;

 function Update () {
     alpha += 10;
     X = x + (a * Mathf.Cos(alpha*.005));
     Y= y + (b * Mathf.Sin(alpha*.005));
     this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3(X,0,Y);
 }
```

EDIT:

if you want it to orbit another object use:

```
     this.gameObject.transform.position = anotherObject.transform.position + Vector3(X,0,Y);
```

Comment: @MickyDuncan As I see, JinJi has offered a customizeable component that moves its GameObject by an elliptic path. What else should they add?

Comment: I have tried the solution at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/133373/moving-object-in-a-ellipse-motion.html but it only changes the orbit inclination, changing x and y change the center of rotation. Could this be to do with the fact I want it orbiting it's parent object? If so how do I get it to work properly?

Comment: @imperium2335 i edited the answer to your new question

Comment: @JinJi Thanks, I will give it a go once I'm home and accept your answer accordingly.