# How to simulate dynamic orbits with unity 2d gravity (realistic)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

I am making a simple game with unity’s 2d game engine and the game involves spacecraft/objects orbiting, accelerating and decelerating. I am wondering if this is possible with the default gravity or possibly by tweaking the default gravity of the rigidbodies/effectors.
I am a beginner learning c# and unity so I am looking for ideas, solutions and reccomendations on what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity 5 moving planets in a circular or elliptical path (orbits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827958/unity-5-moving-planets-in-a-circular-or-elliptical-path-orbits)

Comment: No, I need acceleration, deceleration, changing orbits and fairly realistic physics in terms of simulated (not set) orbits

Comment: ah, when objects move in a circle they always are accelerating so thats what I thought you meant ;)  what have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried the normal physics, but Im not exactly sure if it is realistic enough for orbital physics

Comment: couldn't you just simulate a gravitational pull by adding force in the direction of the object you want to orbit, and then giving the orbiting object an initial velocity?

Comment: Im not sure, I would like it to be that simple, but im not sure if the orbits will be sustainable, and I don’t know how to do the math to find the correct velocity for a circular starting orbit